# How can I create tilt shift alpha mask on the fly?

Tags: android, canvas, gradient

I know I can create with LinearGradient, but I couldn't figure out how to create gradient from inside out.

I want to create something like this, and I want to control the size and the angle of the gradient.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this gradient with the code below.

> ```
>   linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h,
>             new int[]{0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00ffffff, 0x00ffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff},
>             new float[]{0, 0.30f, 0.45f, 0.55f, 0.7f, 1.0f}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
> ```